# .Net -> Get location data (country - state - city) by ip address using only Azure or Google

Tags: .net, dns, geolocation, ip

.Net -> Get location data (country - state - city) by ip address using only Azure or Google

I need to get location data (country - state - city) by ip address
on dotnet but I can use only Azure or Google. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.